# How this code can be modified to improve it's stability to detect eye gaze/pupil?. In low light this code is performing really bad

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, hough-transform

I am using hough-circle transform to detect eye pupil. If there is any shade or abit low light it gets detecting unusual circles around the eyes. I have tried several filters but did not work that much.

I have tried gaussian blur, median blur and blur to reduce the noise but not getting that much results.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

count=0

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    _, frame = cap.read()
    roi = frame[0: 480, 0: 840]
    cv2.imshow("roi",roi)
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_black = np.array([0, 0, 0])
    upper_black = np.array([180, 255, 50])
    mask = cv2.inRange(cimg, lower_black, upper_black)
    mask = cv2.blur(mask,(9,9),0)
    # mask = cv2.medianBlur(mask,)



#circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,300,param1=300,param2=20,minRadius=10,maxRadius=40)
# circles = cv2.HoughCircles(grey,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,minDist=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
#circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,100,200)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(mask,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,300,param1=300,param2=20,minRadius=10,maxRadius=40) 


if circles is None:
    cv2.imshow("roi",mask)
    print ("Not Found")
    continue     

a =circles.tolist()

lst1=[item[0] for item in a[0]]
lst2=[item[1] for item in a[0]]

i=0
left_x=0
right_x=0

while i < len(lst1):
    if (i==0):
        left_x=lst1[i]
    if (i==1):
        right_x=lst1[i]
    i=i+1

i=0
left_y=0
right_y=0

while i < len(lst2):
    if (i==0):
        left_y=lst2[i]
    if (i==1):
        right_y=lst2[i]
    i=i+1

print("whole List")
print(a)
print("Left_X",left_x)
print("Right_X",right_x)
print("Left_y",left_y)
print("Right_y",right_y)




for i in circles[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(mask,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
# draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(mask,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)


# Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('hsv',mask)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to detect the pupils. The circles need to be stable.

Comment: Do you can use some another algorithms? For example tracking and detection approach. You detect with current algorithm. If circles are not detected then use KCF tracking until the next hough success.

Comment: nit: it looks like you are using comments only when they are _not_ needed.